# Having trouble adding Firebase results to array

Tags: json, swift, firebase

When I get data from Firebase, add it to an array, and get the count of it, its count is 4, but there is only one object in the database.

In addition to that when I try to access a value in the array by its index even at 0, I get the error "index out of range".

```
class GroupsViewController: UIViewController {
var groupNames: [String?] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref.child(uid).child("Groups").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                let Dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]

                if Dict != nil {

                    for (groupIds, accesBool) in Dict! {
                        self.loadGroups(groupIds)
                    }

                }
    })
}


func loadGroups(groupID: String) {             
     ref.child("Groups").child(groupID).child("GroupName").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let GroupName = snapshot.value as? String

        print(GroupName) --> Prints the same string 4 times 


        self.groupNames.append(GroupName)


        print(self.groupNames[0]) --> Prints ERROR Index out of range
        print(self.groupNames.count) --> Prints 4



    })


 }
```

Comment: `self.grounNames[0]` -- typo?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the groups in the for loop causes all the problems.

```
class GroupsViewController: UIViewController {
var groupNames: [String?] = []
var groupIdsArr: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref.child(uid).child("Groups").observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                let Dict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]

                if Dict != nil {
                    var newIds: [String] = []
                    for (groupIds, accesBool) in Dict! {
                        newIds.append(groupIds)
                    }
                        self.groupIdsArr = newIds
                        // You can create a loop, that loads each value of the array. I inserted this into a tableview, and used indexPath.row

                        self.loadGroups(groupIdsArr[0])
                }
    })


}


func loadGroups(groupID: String) {             
  ref.child("Groups").child(groupID).child("GroupName").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        let GroupName = snapshot.value as? String

        print(GroupName) --> Prints the same string 4 times 


        self.groupNames.append(GroupName)


        print(self.groupNames[0]) --> Prints ERROR Index out of range
        print(self.groupNames.count) --> Prints 4



    })


 }
```